# How to extract information from custom data type

Tags: haskell, syntax, function-call, custom-data-type

I am new to Haskell and functional programming in general. I am currently learning about custom data types and have the following:

```
data Point = Pt Double Double deriving (Show, Eq)

getValue :: Point -> Double

getValue (Pt a _) = a
```

I am attempting to return only one of the double values from the custom data type but am running into a problem. My console gives me the following error whenever I try to extract one of my point values: "*Couldn't match expected type `Integer -> Integer -> t`*". Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

---

(*edit from OP's comments:*) I typed the following in GHCi

```
test Pt 1.0 1.0
```

Here is the entire error message :

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> Integer -> t’ 
      with actual type ‘Double’ 
• The function ‘test’ is applied to three arguments, 
      but its type ‘Point -> Double’ has only one 
  In the expression: 
      test Pt 1 1 
  In an equation for ‘it’: 
      it = test Pt 1 1 
• Relevant bindings include 
      it :: t (bound at <interactive>:497:1)
```

`test` is what I renamed `getValue` as.

Comment: The code works fine for me when I paste it into GHCi. And it is strange that the error message you report mentions `Integer`s when all the basic types in your code are `Double`s. Please provide the exact code you are using (I suspect there is more and the real error is elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. Unfortunately what I included in the question is the only code I have in my .hs file. It compiles, but when I try to run the test function I'm given the error previously stated.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - so then the question is, what are you doing when you "run the test function"? Do you mean typing some expression in GHCi? If so, what is the precise expression? (The fact that you only include part of the error message - it should also tell you the actual type, and which expression the mismatch occurred in - makes it particularly hard to guess what you might have done.)

Comment: Yes, I typed the following in GHCi "test Pt 1.0 1.0" . Sorry for all the obscurity I didn't want to include the entire message for the sake of not including unnecessary characters. This is the entire error message :    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> Integer -> t’
                  with actual type ‘Double’
    • The function ‘test’ is applied to three arguments,
      but its type ‘Point -> Double’ has only one
      In the expression: test Pt 1 1
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = test Pt 1 1
    • Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:497:1)

Comment: Well you haven't shown me what `test` is, but that's enough to figure out the problem - you clearly want to do `test (Pt 1.0 1.0)`. `test Pt 1.0 1.0` with no parentheses is interpreted as applying the `test` function to the 3 arguments `Pt`, `1.0` and `1.0`, which makes no sense and is why GHC is complaining.

Comment: Sorry, test is what I renamed get_value. However, It works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Please include the complete problem above, instead of the comments. Stackoverflow is primarily for future readers, and leaving part of the problem statement in the comments makes it difficult for people to understand exactly what is happening in an easy way.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've posted your comment as CW answer. if you decide to post your own answer, please ping me so I can delete my post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you clearly want to do `test (Pt 1.0 1.0)`.

`test Pt 1.0 1.0` with no parentheses is interpreted as applying the `test` function to the 3 arguments `Pt`, `1.0` and `1.0`, which makes no sense and is why GHC is complaining. – [Robin Zigmond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8475054/robin-zigmond), [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349430/how-to-extract-information-from-custom-data-type#comment103054013_58349430)